# create a basic contact form on the homepage of a rails app (step by step)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, email, contacts, feedback

I would like to create a simple contact form on a one page site for the user, where the will write to the website owner.

I just need a basic form with this simple fields:
Name
Email
Message (text)

The logic is simple: a user write a feedback in the form >> the app check if everything is correct (I need a validation),take the form inputs and send a mail to a specific email (the admin email).
No data saved, just send a mail.

I am new to RoR (really at the beginning) and I have tried to find some tutorials and gems to create this form with controller, models etc.
But I didn't find a solution...

Everybody could help me?

Please let me know, thanks